# SQL - Collect value from "Select more than one row returned"

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I hava a table A same that

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>ID</td><td style="width:20px"></td>
    <td>Value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td><td style="width:20px"></td>
    <td>A1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td><td style="width:20px"></td>
    <td>B1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td><td style="width:20px"></td>
    <td>C1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td><td style="width:20px"></td>
    <td>A2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td><td style="width:20px"></td>
    <td>B2</td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
```

And I want update value column in table B that select from table A by ID same that

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>ID</td><td style="width:20px"></td>
    <td>Value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td><td style="width:20px"></td>
    <td>A1;A2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td><td style="width:20px"></td>
    <td>B1;B2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td><td style="width:20px"></td>
    <td>C1</td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
```

I have run this query:

```
update B
    set B.value = (select A.value from A where A.ID = B.ID);
```

but it show "ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression"

How can I resolve it? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `string_agg()`:

```
update B
    set B.value = (select string_agg(A.value, ';')
                   from A
                   where A.ID = B.ID
                  );
```